# UITableView cells delete ingloriously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been reading a lot about updating a UITableView after you remove rows by both IndexPath and the datasource, which it seems like comes down to `[tableView startUpdates]`, run whatever update code you have, then `[tableView endUpdates]`.

Despite following numerous examples to a T, and utilizing `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:<indexPaths> withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];`
, I can't seem to make my rows delete in any way but what the following depicts:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6ov1FR0R4g&feature=youtu.be (essentially, if there are n > 1 rows, the row will simply blink out, and if there is n = 1 row, it will slide outward, stop, then disappear).

I'd really like a smoother behavior, like, perhaps, the row slides out, as the row slides up. Here's the code executing the deletion:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int idx = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1];
    LoLoanedItemDoc *itemDoc = [[self items] objectAtIndex:idx];

    // Delete notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:[[itemDoc data] notification]];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    // Remove from datasource
    [[self items] removeObject:itemDoc];

    [tableView endUpdates];

    // Delete folder
    [itemDoc deleteDoc];
}
```

Comment: Try removing the begin and end updates,, they're not needed in this situation.

Comment: I always change my model first, then do updates.  Was under the impression that not doing so would raise an exception when you tell the tableview to delete and the model count stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it two ways, both of which work for me.

*Delete the item before you perform the updates.*

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //Delete the item from the data source
        [self removeProductFromQuoteAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        //Do the updates
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

---

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [shipping removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Are you performing any type of operation on the cell before it deletes? (like closing the drawer animation you have).

Comment: I'm still trying to work on your solution, but it doesn't seem like it changes the behavior. As far as cell operations go, no, I'm not doing anything like that. Just a very simple remove from datasource, remove from local store and remove from tableview.

Comment: You could also try changing UITableViewRowAnimationTop to UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic. I've had the animation act funny at times.

Comment: I'm going to give you the "selected answer" with a follow up: Turns out I was resetting my datasource and reloading my view elsewhere before the animation could finish. I stripped out this aspect (I don't honestly know why I was doing it that way to begin with), and it works fine.

Comment: @dclowd9901 ah I see, thanks for the selection however, glad you were able to get it fixed.